# What's the algorithm behind MySQL's sha256_password hashing scheme?

Tags: authentication, passwords, hash

MySQL's old `mysql_native_password` hashing scheme was the equivalent of this in PHP:

```
sha1(sha1('password', true));
```

That's a hex-encoded SHA-1 hash of a binary SHA-1 hash of the password, without any salting.

MySQL 8.0 introduced a two variants of a new hashing scheme based on SHA256 called `caching_sha2_password` and `sha256_password`, the former being the default ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html)). Despite their name, neither appears to be vanilla SHA256.

(Yes, I know SHA256 is not a great choice for password hashing, but it's a lot better than SHA-1 and it wasn't up to me!)

Here's an example. I created a hash for the password `password`, and it created a mysql.users password hash like this:

```
$A$005$wU"H/k5|5;f!kP_&N4cvqu6bppuYjCvqhg2blU.NcJHkkhaVj.QNt7pipg4p3
```

I'm guessing that (separating by `$` chars), `A` means it's SHA256 (the scheme may support other SHA2 variants in future), and that the `005` is a salt, but the rest of the string isn't a common format - it doesn't look like either regular hex output or base64, nor is it raw binary.

Can anyone tell me the actual algorithms for these new schemes, in PHP or similar code?

### Update

Thanks to @kelalaka for some important pointers, I had a crack at writing this in PHP:

```
$originalhash = 'wU"H/k5|5;f!kP_&N4cvqu6bppuYjCvqhg2blU.NcJHkkhaVj.QNt7pipg4p3';
$binaryhash = base64_decode($originalhash);
$salt_length = 20;
$hash_length = 43;
$rawsalt = substr($binaryhash, 0, $salt_length);
$rawhash = substr($binaryhash, $salt_length);

$password = 'password';
$iterations = 5;
$iteration_multiplier = 1000;
$it = $iterations * $iteration_multiplier;
$hash = $rawsalt . $password;
for ($i = 0; $i < $it; $i++) {
    $hash = substr(hash('sha256', $hash, true), 0, $hash_length);
}
$hashoutput = base64_encode($rawsalt . $hash);
var_dump($originalhash, $hashoutput);
```

However, this doesn't produce matching output:

```
string(61) "wU"H/k5|5;f!kP_&N4cvqu6bppuYjCvqhg2blU.NcJHkkhaVj.QNt7pipg4p3"
string(72) "wUH/k55fkPN4cvqu6bppuYjCvqgx75cg5UeVzAVpx0OzU7KS2Klujh3rbHzrAena3/MBAA=="
```

- It's too long
- I suspect the encoding scheme is not base64; notice the salt diverges from the original even though it is unchanged.
- I'm not sure whether the starting string should be salt + password or password + salt.
- I'm not clear when the truncation of the binary hash should be performed - in the loop, or after?

Comment: You need more than that, [serialize](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/ea7d2e2d16ac03afdd9cb72a972a95981107bf51/sql/auth/sha2_password.cc#L540). See `serialized_string.append(salt.c_str(), salt.length());
`. It uses `https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/4869291f7ee258e136ef03f5a50135fe7329ffb9/mysys/crypt_genhash_impl.cc` and there base64 is applied. Note that, you turned this question into a SO question, not Information securiy.

Comment: Seems I can't move it myself, but at least I voted to do so!

Comment: I twas better to keep it before the coding updates, accepting it and asking a new question on SO based on the knowledge. Unfortunately,  changing the question is not a good act once it got an answer...

Comment: I don't see why it expects a sha256 hash to be 43 chars long: it's 64 in hex, 32 in binary, 41 in base64. The hash that I see in the DB is not valid base64 - it has too many different non-alphanumeric chars (`"/|;!_.&`).

Comment: Also keep an eye on https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2305 - discussion of exact algorithm should eventually surface there.

Comment: Interesting, thanks - it could be that my "original hash" string contains control chars and is filtered for display by the MySQL CLI client. It still looks base64-ish and not binary-ish enough for me though; I'd expect it to look less alphanumeric if it was raw hash function output.

Comment: Yeah, exactly - it's a Frankenstein mashup of human-readable and binary that I believe is either a bug, or a misguided understanding of what \$[type]\$[salt]\$[hash] notation is for. I'm tempted to file a bug with the MySQL project about it. And looks like philsmd figured it out - see the GitHub. Basically a sha256crypt variant, default 5000 rounds, with a 20-byte *raw binary* salt (which is *highly* unusual and, IMO, an implementation error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Server Blog](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/), it is:

> The advantage of mysql_native_password is that it support challenge-response mechanism which is very quick and does not require encrypted connection. However, mysql_native_password relies on SHA1 algorithm and NIST has suggested to stop using it.
>
> caching_sha2_password tries to combine the best of both worlds.

`XOR( SHA256(pwd),SHA256(SHA256SHA256(pwd)) , Nonce)`

[image]

> \$A\$005\$wU"H/k5|5;f!kP_&N4cvqu6bppuYjCvqhg2blU.NcJHkkhaVj.QNt7pipg4p3

From the source code [sha2_password.cc](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/ea7d2e2d16ac03afdd9cb72a972a95981107bf51/sql/auth/sha2_password.cc#L397)

- > Expected format
  >
  > DELIMITER[digest_type]DELIMITER[iterations]DELIMITER[salt][digest]

Where the delimiter is `$`

- > digest_type:
  >
  > A => SHA256
- > iterations:
  >
  > 005 => 5*ITERATION_MULTIPLIER
- > salt:
  >
  > Random string. Length SALT_LENGTH
- > digest:
  >
  > SHA2 digest. Length STORED_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH

  From file [i_sha2_password.h](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8e797a5d6eb3a87f16498edcb7261a75897babae/sql/auth/i_sha2_password.h)
- > #define CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH 20
  >
  > const unsigned int STORED_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH = 43;

Comment: That's useful, but not quite there - this tells me how the password is used in an auth conversation. When it's generated on the server, there is no nonce involved. The code sample suggests it's 3 rounds of regular sha256, but that's nothing like what I get out of it - I added an example to demonstrate.

Comment: @Synchro I've looked into source code to figure out what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm implemented in hashcat works for me with mysql 8.0.

```
<?php

// based on https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/master/tools/test_modules/m07400.pm

function to64($v, $n) {
    # ('.', '/', '0'..'9', 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z');
    $i64 = array_merge(array('.', '/'), range('0', '9'), range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'));

    $str = '';
    while (--$n >= 0) {
        $str .= $i64[$v & 0x3F];
        $v >>= 6;
    }
    return $str;
}

function sha256($data) {
    return hash("sha256", $data, true);
}

function sha_crypts($func, $bits, $key, $salt, $loops) {
    $bytes = $bits / 8;
    $b = $func($key . $salt . $key);

    # Add for any character in the key one byte of the alternate sum.

    $tmp = $key . $salt;

    for ($i = strlen($key); $i > 0; $i -= $bytes) {
        if ($i > $bytes) {
            $tmp .= $b;
        } else {
            $tmp .= substr ($b, 0, $i);
        }
    }

    # Take the binary representation of the length of the key and for every 1 add the alternate sum, for every 0 the key.

    for ($i = strlen($key); $i > 0; $i >>= 1) {
        if (($i & 1) != 0) {
            $tmp .= $b;
        } else {
            $tmp .= $key;
        }
    }

    $a = $func($tmp);

    # NOTE, this will be the 'initial' $c value in the inner loop.

    # For every character in the password add the entire password.  produces DP

    $tmp = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($key); $i++) {
        $tmp .= $key;
    }

    $dp = $func($tmp);

    # Create byte sequence P

    $p = "";

    for ($i = strlen($key); $i > 0; $i -= $bytes) {
        if ($i > $bytes) {
            $p .= $dp;
        } else {
            $p .= substr ($dp, 0, $i);
        }
    }

    # produce ds

    $tmp = "";

    $til = 16 + ord (substr ($a, 0, 1));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $til; $i++) {
        $tmp .= $salt;
    }

    $ds = $func($tmp);

    # Create byte sequence S

    $s = "";

    for ($i = strlen($salt); $i > 0; $i -= $bytes) {
        if ($i > $bytes) {
            $s .= $ds;
        } else {
            $s .= substr ($ds, 0, $i);
        }
    }

    $c = $a; # Ok, we saved this, which will 'seed' our crypt value here in the loop.

    # now we do 5000 iterations of SHA2 (256 or 512)

    for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
        if ($i & 1) { $tmp  = $p; }
        else        { $tmp  = $c; }

        if ($i % 3) { $tmp .= $s; }
        if ($i % 7) { $tmp .= $p; }

        if ($i & 1) { $tmp .= $c; }
        else        { $tmp .= $p; }

        $c = $func($tmp);
    }

    #my $inc1; my $inc2; my $mod; my $end;

    if ($bits == 256) { $inc1 = 10; $inc2 = 21; $mod = 30; $end =  0; }
    else              { $inc1 = 21; $inc2 = 22; $mod = 63; $end = 21; }

    $i = 0;
    $tmp = "";

    do {
        $tmp .= to64 ((ord (substr ($c, $i, 1)) << 16) | (ord (substr ($c, ($i + $inc1) % $mod, 1)) << 8) | ord (substr ($c, ($i + $inc1 * 2) % $mod, 1)), 4);
        $i = ($i + $inc2) % $mod;
    } while ($i != $end);

    if ($bits == 256) { $tmp .= to64 ((ord (substr ($c, 31, 1)) << 8) | ord (substr ($c, 30, 1)), 3); }
    else              { $tmp .= to64  (ord (substr ($c, 63, 1)), 2); }

    return $tmp;
}

# pass - string
# salt - 20 bytes in utf8 compatible binary form
function mysql_caching_sha2_password($pass, $saltbin) {
    $count = 5;
    $iter = 1000 * $count;

    $dgst = sha_crypts("sha256", 256, $pass, $saltbin, $iter);

    $hash = sprintf ("\\\$A\\\$%03d\\\$%s%s", $count, $saltbin, $dgst);
    return $hash;
}

function gen_utf8_salt($len) {
    $r = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        // Generate a random Unicode code point between U+0020 and U+007E
        $codePoint = mt_rand(0x0020, 0x007E);
        // Convert the code point to a UTF-8 string
        $r .= mb_convert_encoding('&#'.intval($codePoint).';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    }
    return $r;
}


$pass = "ąśóżźńÓĄŻŹŃ";
print("for password: $pass\n");
$saltbin = gen_utf8_salt(20);
$hash = mysql_caching_sha2_password($pass, $saltbin);
print("newbin: " . $hash . "\n");
print("newhex: " . strtoupper(current(unpack("H*", $hash))) . "\n");
```

Format used is:

```
$A$count$<salt><hash>
```

salt: 20 bytes binary (needs to be in utf-8 range)

hash: sha256 crypt of count*1000 rounds of binary data and salt

Comment: This is just a full-code answer that does not suit our site. Better post in GitHub etc. and comment or explain the code here.